# Mysql trigger to insert the row if not exist in table but doesn't work

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger to check if a row with the same subject and object names is created. If not, I want to insert it else I will show an error message.

I have looked up some examples and written the code below but there are some errors.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER insertOnceKB BEFORE INSERT ON knowledgebase FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NEW.Object, NEW.Subject, NEW.Predicate not in 
(SELECT A.Object, A.Subject, A.Predicate FROM knowledgebase as A 
 where (NEW.Object = A.Object and NEW.Subject = A.Subject and NEW.Predicate = A.Predicate)) THEN
    INSERT INTO knowledgebase (Object,Predicate,Subject,Count,botID,Source,EntityTypeID)
        VALUES ( NEW.Object, NEW.Predicate, NEW.Subject, NEW.Count, NEW.botID, NEW.Source, NEW.EntityTypeID);
THEN
    CALL `Insert not allowed`;
END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

This is the error message that Xampp server showed:

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near ' NEW.Subject, NEW.Predicate not in  (SELECT A.Object, A.Subject,
> A.Predicate FR' at line 3

Comment: Your second THEN should be an else AND a suggest you declare some variables and move the select out of the if statement amend it to insert to variables and test the variables or change the test to an exists/not exists test. Either way sample data would be useful.AND what's the insert for - you cannot insert to the table which fired the trigger..

Comment: You are right about inserting. How can I check if the same values already exist on db before inserting? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this statement

```
IF NEW.Object, NEW.Subject, NEW.Predicate not in (SELECT A.Object, A.Subject, A.Predicate FROM knowledgebase as A where (NEW.Object = A.Object and NEW.Subject = A.Subject and NEW.Predicate = A.Predicate))
```

is wrong, even if it works out, I don't think a trigger would allow to query the very table you're about to insert in, but anyway,

you can do it this way

```
if exists( select * from knowledgebase as a where new.Subject = a.Subject and new.Predicate = a.Predicate and new.Object = a.Object ) then
 return bla bla bla;
else if
 do whatever you were doing...
end if
```

Comment: Thanks, " I don't think a trigger would allow to query the very table you're about to insert in"  this is true, it didn't allow. how can I check it?